# Was there a study of Palestinian public opinion related to the impact of videos from Hamas' October 7th attack on Israel?

Tags: palestine, public-opinion

[A recent *Frontline* investigation called "Israel's Second Front"](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/frontline/documentary/israels-second-front/) includes an interview with political scientist [Khalil Shikaki](https://www.pcpsr.org/en/node/192). Shortly after the 9:30 mark of the overall episode, Dr. Shikaki states:

> Those [Palestinians] who saw the videos were 10 times more likely to come to the conclusion that Hamas committed atrocities. Ten times more likely than those who did not. The majority of Palestinians today, however, does not buy into the Israeli narrative of what happened on October the 7th.

Was such a study conducted and does it support the assertion made here? I find it plausible but can't find any specific citations or documentations of what he is referring to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This refers to the same [PCPSR survey](https://pcpsr.org/en/node/963) published on Dec 13:

> Those who say that Hamas did not commit the atrocities seen in the videos are higher in the West Bank (97%) compared to the Gaza Strip (83%), among the religious and the somewhat religious (91% and 92% respectively), compared to the non-religious (75%) and among supporters of Hamas (97%) compared to supporters of Fateh and other forces (85% and 81% respectively). **Belief that Hamas fighters have committed atrocities against civilians is also higher among those who did watch videos showing such atrocities (31%) compared to those who did not (3%). In the Gaza Strip, 41% of those who watched the videos believe that Hamas did commit these atrocities while only 8% of those who did not watch these videos believe that Hamas committed atrocities.**

I think the middle sentence (with the 10:1 ratio) thus refers [only] to the West Bank. (It was about 5:1 in Gaza.)

Also, this doesn't look like a controlled (cause -> effect) experiment. Those who were more inclined to believe that Hamas committed atrocities might also have been more likely to seek out such videos. There's a para before that covered the Q if they did see videos:

> 85% say they did not see videos, shown by international news outlets, showing acts committed by Hamas against Israeli civilians, such as the killing of women and children in their homes; only 14% saw these videos.  The percentage of those who say they have seen these videos is higher in the Gaza Strip (25%) compared to the West Bank (7%), among the non-religious (31%) compared to the religious (15%), and among supporters of other forces and supporters of Fateh (21% and 20% respectively) compared to supporters of Hamas (12%).

(And of course, some may have seen videos but claimed in the survey response that they didn't. The survey had no way to double check that.)

Comment: A similar question about this survey was posted on [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/84338/2130)